# Any copies of the google drive binaries (c#) with strong name signing?

Tags: dll, google-drive-api, signing

I'm looking to build an integration into one of my current projects involving GDrive, however I can not currently use the released binary package from https://developers.google.com/drive/downloads as it does not have strong name dlls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C# client library doesn't have binaries with strong name signing. You may like to figure out building them by yourself, the code is open sourced on https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/